# How to pivot and get the mean values of each column to rows

Tags: python, pandas

I'm new in python and I need your assistance with getting the result when you add your columns as value and your values in rows.

Here's an example:

columns

```
A   B   C
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

Expected result:

```
   avg
A   4
B   5
C   6
```

I can do it easily in excel by placing the columns in "Values" the move the values in rows to get the average but I can't seem to do it in python.

Comment: Is your data in a 2D list, dict, 2D array, or `pandas` dataframe? is that a decision you have yet to make?

Comment: It's actually a pandas dataframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,4,7],'B':[2,5,8],'C':[3,6,9]})
df
   A  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

ser=df.mean()    #Result is a Series
df=pd.DataFrame({'avg':ser})   #Convert this Series into DataFrame
df 
   avg
A  4.0
B  5.0
C  6.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `to_frame`

```
df.mean().to_frame('ave')
Out[186]: 
   ave
A  4.0
B  5.0
C  6.0
```